# How to display Form/Survey results

Tags: forms, information-design

I made an attempt to display form results in a readable and user friendly format. I think there are certainly better ways to do this but right now have no idea how to proceed. The form results are displayed in a pop-up and the green bar on the right is a scroll bar.

Do you have any ideas or examples of user friendly display of forms and surveys?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't display the information as you would with in a form.

I would prefer Image at the top and information below it to start with. Have background of both label and filed same.

If the pop-up is just for the information purpose, I think you can even let labels go away. And maybe use icons instead.

**Something like this**

[image]

Comment: Thank you ... but I wasn't clear enough. This is a custom form that clients can create by themselves so I can't create it as a card type like you proposed. Form can have numerous custom fields so you can easily have 3 pictures and 5 yes/no answers.

Comment: In that case, you can move the labels above the input fields, user will probably have to scroll a bit more, but that way you can avoid having too much white space. And you can still use icons for the vanity purpose.